# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationContext() from the type ContextWrapper - Android

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I created am working on a class for storing toast themes and creating toasts.  I am currently testing it in a fragment, so I guess it needs to be static.  The problem is that 
I can't figure out how to pass the application context.  I get this error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationContext() from the type ContextWrapper
```

I understand why I get this error, but I don't know the correct way to do it.
I have searched the forum for similar errors, and I haven't found the answer.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
        implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

    private static DWAWebGet webGet = new DWAWebGet();

    private static DWAToaster toaster = 
        new DWAToaster(getApplicationContext())
            .makeToast("error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG,Gravity.TOP,0,0)
            .makeToast("alert",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,Gravity.TOP,0,0)
            .makeToast("msg",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,Gravity.TOP,0,0);

    ...

    public static class SectionFragment_sign_in extends Fragment {

        ...

        public void click_register_button(View view) {

            TextView email_TextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.register_email_input);
            TextView pass1_TextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.register_pass1_input);
            TextView pass2_TextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.register_pass2_input);

            String email = email_TextView.getText().toString();
            String pass1 = pass1_TextView.getText().toString();
            String pass2 = pass2_TextView.getText().toString();

            webGet.waitGet(
                    "https",
                    "...",
                    "/app/menu/data/register/",
                    "email="+webGet.encode(email)
                    +"&pass1="+webGet.encode(pass1)
                    +"&pass2="+webGet.encode(pass2),
                    new RegisterResponseHandler(),
                    toaster
                    );

        }

        public class RegisterResponseHandler 
                extends DWAWebGet.Handler<DWAWebGet.Response> {

            public RegisterResponseHandler () {
                new DWAWebGet().super();
            }

            public void handle (DWAWebGet.Response r) {

                String status;
                String error;

                if ((status = r.getMap("status").getStr()) == null) {
                    toaster.error("Response Status: null");
                } else if (status == "denied") {
                    if ((error = r.getMap("error").getStr()) == null) error = "No Reason Given";    
                    toaster.alert("Registration Denied: " +  error);
                } else if (status != "good") {
                    if ((error = r.getMap("error").getStr()) == null) error = "blank";
                    toaster.error("Response Status: " + status + ", Error: "+error);
                } else {
                    toaster.msg("Registration Complete. Please check your email and verify your email address.");
                    ((MainActivity) SectionFragment_sign_in .this.getActivity())
                .prefs_edit.putString("id_email",r.getMap("email").getStr());
                    ((TextView) ((MainActivity) SectionFragment_sign_in .this.getActivity())
                            .findViewById(R.id.sign_in_email_input))
                            .setText(r.getMap("email").getStr());
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `new DWAToaster(MainActivity.this)` . use activity context.

Comment: "Cannot use this in static context"

Comment: you cannot use `this` that in static class.

Comment: you can use `getActivity()` to get the context of the hosting activity.

Comment: It works when I use new DWAToaster(), use DWAToaster extends Fragment, and  put getActivity() in DWAToaster, but I don't know if this is a good way to do it, or if it will work in any apps I create where MainActivity does is not a FragmentActivity.

Comment: If I use new DWAToaster(getActivity()), I get The Method getAcvivity is undefined for MainActivity.

Comment: remove static modifier for `private static DWAToaster toaster`. remove static modifiers if not required.

Comment: If I remove the static modifier, I get many errors using toaster when I use the toaster in static fragments.

Comment: if you need context in `SectionFragment_sign_in` you can use `view.getContext()`. ALso move this `private static DWAToaster toaster` inside `SectionFragment_sign_in` since you are using the same inside the fragment class.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/1aPZXZG6kWk. Avoid non-static inner classes in an activity if you don't control their life cycle, use a static inner class and make a weak reference to the activity inside. The solution to this issue is to use a static inner class with a WeakReference to the outer class, as done in ViewRoot and its W inner class for instance. http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html. check both links and the solution by romain guy.